# Kubernetes pods are running but docker ps does not give any output

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have been trying to run tomcat container on port 5000 on cluster using kubernetes. But when i am using kubectl create -f tmocat_pod.yaml , it creates pod but docker ps does not give any output. Why is it so?

Ideally, when it is running a pod, it means it is running a container inside that pod and that container is defined in yaml file.
Why is that docker ps does not show any containers running?
I am following the below URLs:

- http://containertutorials.com/get_started_kubernetes/k8s_example.html
- https://blog.jetstack.io/blog/k8s-getting-started-part2/

How can I get it running and see tomcat running on browser on port 5000.

Comment: just checking: is it possible you're doing `docker ps` on the master and the pod is schedule on another node?

Comment: I have same issue, I was tying to setup kubernetes node manually, as an initial stage I have only one node which is master and surprisingly kubectl shows  my nginx pod running successfully, but its not running successfully, to debug I checked docker ps -a and it doesn't show the container

Answer (score 13):

The docker containers should be running on the virtual machine. Since I only installed minikube on my local machine, I confirmed the following will bring what you want:

```
minikub ssh
...
docker ps
```

Just try the kubernetes equivalent of `minikube ssh`.

Answer (score 3):

In Kubernetes, Docker contaienrs are run on Pods, and Pods are run on Nodes, and Nodes are run on your machine (minikube/GKE)

When you run `kubectl create -f tmocat_pod.yaml` you basically create a pod and it runs the docker container on that pod.

The node that holds this pod, is basically a virtual instance, if you could 'SSH' into that node, docker ps would work.

What you need is:
`kubectl get pods` <-- It is like docker ps, it shows you all the pods (think of it as docker containers) running

`kubectl get nodes` <-- view the host machines for your pods.

`kubectl describe pods <pod-name>`    <-- view *system logs* for your pods.

`kubectl logs <pod-name>` <-- Will give you logs for the specific pod.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect your Terminal with the docker server what is running inside your Node/VM.

With this **command** in your terminal: `eval $(minikube docker-env)`

- This only configures your **current** terminal window.
- [illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fig9F.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

may be you are not using docker as container runtime.
I faced the same issue, and i forgot that i switched to gVisor with `runsc` as handler.

```sh
cat /etc/default/kubelet
```

```
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS="--container-runtime remote --container-runtime-endpoint unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock"
```

If so, you need to use `runsc` command instead of docker.

Comment: The cat cmd does not work for me. I used this way to find what is the container runtime.

```kubectl get nodes -o wide```


For docker , you will see something like this:
``` NAME         STATUS   VERSION    CONTAINER-RUNTIME
node-1       Ready    v1.16.15   docker://19.3.1
node-2       Ready    v1.16.15   docker://19.3.1
```
ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/find-out-runtime-you-use/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you are running the `docker ps` command, but if you are trying to do that from your host machine and the k8s cluster is located elsewhere, i.e. your machine is not a node in the cluster, `docker ps` will not return anything since the containers are not tied to your docker host.

Assuming your pod is running, `kubectl get pods` will display all of your running pods. To check further details, you can use `kubectl describe pod <yourpodname>` to check the status of each container (in great detail). To get the pod names, you should be able to use tab-complete with the kubernetes cli. Also, if your pod contains multiple containers, you will need to give the container name as well, which you can use tab-complete for after you've selected your pod.

The output will look similar to:

```
kubectl describe pod comparison-api-dply-reborn-6ffb88b46b-s2mtx
Name:           comparison-api-dply-reborn-6ffb88b46b-s2mtx
Namespace:      default
Node:           aks-nodepool1-99697518-0/10.240.0.5
Start Time:     Fri, 20 Apr 2018 14:08:21 -0400
Labels:         app=comparison-pod-reborn
                pod-template-hash=2996446026
...
Status:         Running
IP:             *.*.*.*
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/comparison-api-dply-reborn-6ffb88b46b
Containers:
  rabbit-mq:
    ...
    Port:           5672/TCP
    State:          Running
    ...
```

If your containers and pods are already running, then you shouldn't need to troubleshoot them too much. To make them accessible from the Public Internet, take a look at Services (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to make your API's IP address fixed and easily reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a "docker ps -a" to see if the container is dead? If it is there you can see its logs with "docker logs " and maybe this gives you a hint.

Comment: It does not list either.How do i access my tomcat container running inside pod from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If your pod is running successfully and if you are looking for the container on the node where the pod is scheduled the issue could be kubernetes is using a different container runtime.

Example

```
root@renjith-laptop:/home/renjith/raspbery-k8s# kubectl exec -it nginx-8586cf59-h92ct bash
root@nginx-8586cf59-h92ct:/# exit
exit
root@renjith-laptop:/home/renjith/raspbery-k8s# kubectl get po -o wide
NAME                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP         NODE
nginx-8586cf59-h92ct   1/1       Running   0          47s      10.20.0.3   renjith-laptop
root@renjith-laptop:/home/renjith/raspbery-k8s# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
root@renjith-laptop:/home/renjith/raspbery-k8s#
```

Here I am able exec to the pod, and I am in the same node where pod is scheduled, but `docker ps` doesn't show the container. In my case kubelet is using different container runtime, one of the argument to kubelet service  is `--container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/cri-containerd.sock`

Answer (score 0):

From Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/) to get container images running on your system:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}" |\
tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |\
sort |\
uniq -c
```

Then you get back something like:

```
  2 registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.9.3
  1 registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0
  1 registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.1
  1 registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.1
  3 registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.1
  1 registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's using containerd runtime. Please use below command to list containers created for kubernetes namespace.

## ctr -n k8s.io containers list

```
CONTAINER                                                           IMAGE                                                              RUNTIME                  
0d27236ea30764532e64e2972764c211b1e0c96fd8aa9d627d227bdb60fb8d67    registry.k8s.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.6.4               io.containerd.runc.v2    
2946d744d6a8a62cffcc7f8f294e6125f3928cf8b83c61795c79b425ad7d9b1f    registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6                                          io.containerd.runc.v2
```